# Separating/accessing a triple tuple list like [[[x,y],z],p]?

Tags: python

I am trying to access variables stored in a triple tuple list in python and I am not sure how to do it. I would like to be able to go through the list in a for loop and get x,y,x, & p from each tuple. How would I do that?

```
MovesList = [  [[[1,2],3],1] , [[[2,5],3],1] , [[[1,3],0],2]  ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unpack tuples as you iterate over them:

Python 2:

```
>>> for ((x,y),z),p in MovesList:
...     print x, y, z, p
```

Python 3:

```
>>> for ((x,y),z),p in MovesList:
...     print(x,y,z,p)
```

Both of which result in:

```
1 2 3 1
2 5 3 1
1 3 0 2
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre is there a way to great a move out of moves list one at a time like: var `x,y,z,p = MovesList[0]` so I could go through a while loop `while(MovesList[0] != Null):` until the list is empty and still access x,y,z,&p?

Comment: @NickZulanas Why do you want to use a `while` loop? The `for` loop will iterate over each `move` in `MovesList`. That should be what you want. The code you provided in your comment is not valid Python and can't actually iterate over the `move`s in `MovesList`. You may need to clarify what you want.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks for the help @FamousJameous

Answer (score 0):

same unpacking with list comprehension

```
In [202]: [[x,y,z,p] for ([[x,y],z],p) in MovesList]
Out[202]: [[1, 2, 3, 1], [2, 5, 3, 1], [1, 3, 0, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found you can unpack a list of tuples that doesn't have a finite space by putting it through a while loop like so:

```
Mylist = list()
MyOtherList = list()
//list is packed my tuples of four {(a,b,c,d),(a,b,c,d),(a,b,c,d),...}
While MyList[0] != Null:
     var w = MyList[0][0]
     var x = MyList[0][1]
     var y = MyList[0][2]
     var z = MyList[0][3]
     MyList.Remove(w,x,y,z)
     //do something with w,x,y,z based upon use
     MyOtherList = getMoreListItems(w,x,y,z)
     MyList.extend(MyOtherList)
```

This can be used when the list you would like to iterate through is full of tuples of all the same size